# Image Rotation in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I am having problem while rotating the image in IE 8 , it works perfect in other browsers(Chrome,Mozilla,Firefox).

Is there any other way for this except filter `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Basic Image(rotation)` as I am having some problem while using this filter in zooming the image in IE 8.

After a perticular level of zoom ,image resets to its normal rotation(Angle 0) before that zoom level everything goes perfect but once this scenario occurs image resets on every zoom level on rotation of image. I think it may be the filters issue.

if any good article is there for the same then kindly share , this can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` property is CSS3 and is not supported in IE8. Your only options are to use the filter property, or draw vector shapes using [VML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

IE's old `filter` styles are notoriously buggy. Thank goodness it's less of an issue now that modern IE versions don't need it any more.

Yes, it's possible to use them to do things like rotation and gradients, etc in older IE versions, but you have to be careful to understand that they are ActiveX controls, and not a native part of the browser.

This means that they have some limitations and quirks, some of which *cannot* be worked around. In particular, you will have problems if you try to combine them with other browser features that modify the element or the layout around it.

I've never tried using `zoom` in conjunction with a filter rotation, but it sounds like a classic case of features that may not work well together. If that's the case, you may simply have to accept that it's not going to work in old IE versions.

Perhaps you could find an alternative way to do what you want without using `zoom`? If it's a text element, maybe doubling the `font-size` would do the trick? Or if it's an image, maybe increasing the width and height and letting the browser scale the image for you.

If none of that works, the final solution may simply be to provide IE8 users with a slightly less exciting version of your site that doesn't do zooming and rotation quite a much as it does in other browsers.