# How can I rotate an image in IE8 using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Stuck with Prototype. Here's a jsfiddle, but you'll have to use the DRAFT feature (http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#draft-page) to see it in IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/7rxaE/

```
<image id="spinner" src="http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transfers/100/239327-loading_spinner-32.png">
<script>
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        angle += 0.1;

        $('spinner').setStyle({
            '-ms-filter': '"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(' +
                            'SizingMethod = \'auto expand\', ' +
                            'M11 = ' + Math.cos(angle) + ', ' +
                            'M12 = ' + -Math.sin(angle) + ', ' +
                            'M21 = ' + Math.sin(angle) + ', ' +
                            'M22 = ' + Math.cos(angle) + ')"'
        });
    }, 16);
</script>
```

I'm open to better ideas for the spinner; animated gif won't work for me for a number of reasons.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415825/image-rotation-in-ie8

Comment: Possibly drop the `-ms-`, can't remember for sure, but have a feeling that the prefix was added later. Also, the snarky side of me wants to ask what year it is! Haven't seen prototype for a long time! :)

Comment: Had to drop the `-ms-` and the double quotes. Thanks @RichBradshaw. Make it an answer if you want 15 points bad enough. Prototype still powers some old money makers!

Comment: Why not, points mean prizes right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `-ms-` and the ". IE 8 uses the:

```
filter: property
```

syntax rather than the newer.

```
-ms-filter: "property"
```

Comment: Actually, the ``-ms-filter`` was first added in IE8 and now removed in IE10 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx). It's most likely the prototype messing it up.